# How to compare two list and add all list to new list ASP.Net MVC 4 using linq

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, arraylist, list-comparison

I have two list 
**List A**

```
List<test> populate = new List<test>();
{
  populate.Add(new test(){ID = 1, name="AAA", nameID=1, type=1, isSelected=false});
  populate.Add(new test(){ID = 2, name="BBB", nameID=2, type=1, isSelected=false});
  populate.Add(new test(){ID = 3, name="CCC", nameID=3, type=1, isSelected=false});
}
```

**List B**

```
    List<build> populateBuild = new List<build>();
{
  populateBuild.Add(new test(){ID = 1, name="AAA", nameID=1, type=1, isSelected=false});
  populateBuild.Add(new test(){ID = 3, name="CCC", nameID=3, type=1, isSelected=false});
}
```

**What I want to achieve is:**
1) I want new list, (List C)
2) In **List C**, I want all the data in **List A**, but the **value of isSelected** in **List A**, will changed to **TRUE**, when it is compared to data in **List B**
3) Means, if **List B is exist in list A**, the **value of isSelected** in list A will **changed to TRUE** and added to **list C**
4) if List B is **not exist** in List A, it will still be added to List C, but without changing the isSelected value(remain false).

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean `List<test> populateBuild = new List<test>();` (not `List<build>`). You can generate the 3rd list using

```
// Get the ID's of the 2nd list
IEnumerable<int> populateBuildIds = populateBuild.Select(x => x.ID);
// Initialize the 3rd list
List<test> listC = new List<test>();
// Copy all elements from the first list and update the isSelected property
foreach (test t in populate)
{
    listC.Add(new test()
    {
        ID = t.ID, 
        name = t.name, 
        nameID = t.nameID, 
        type = t.type, 
        isSelected = populateBuildIds.Contains(t.ID) // true if also in 2nd list
    });
}
```

Comment: just to confirm that, do you mean that if the id is also in 2nd list means the isSelected is automatically changed to true?

Comment: Yes, that correct (and if its not in the 2nd list it will be `false`)

Comment: the code run smoothly but i dnt know whether the isSelected is changed to true or not. I want to display  listC as checkbox in my razor.So when I displayed it, it shows all the data from the list with unchecked checkbox(means false) .since the isSelected is changed to true, means the checkbox should be checked as well right?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. If the view is a model of `listC`(IEnumerable<test>`) and your using a `for` loop to generate the view, then the 1st and 3rd items will be checked, and the 2nd will be unchecked (I can create a quick DotNetFiddle if your not understanding). If the checkbox is not displaying the correct 'checked' status, it means you view is wrong

Comment: i think my view is wrong hehe.. i would appreciate if you could create the dotNetFiddle for a clearer point of view ..

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fOW2ev). Note I will delete this later, so if you want to keep it, you will need to fork it

Comment: Yep, it works, hehe . TQ so much for your guidance and time.Really appreciated it. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117272/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user3643092).

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona esta classe no seu projeto:

```
   public static class LINQToObjectExtensions
    {
        public static void UpdateAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
                action(item);
        }
    }
```

depois executa desta maneira:

```
ListC.UpdateAll(p => p.isSelected = ListB.Contains(p));
```